# Branch.io redirect crawlers to Google Play

Tags: android, ios, deep-linking, branch.io

My branch.io link works as expected for iOS, Android, and Desktop, except when I look at what the crawler sees. How do I tell all crawlers using a branch.io link to go to the Google Play page of my app (so I get the backlinks)?

Answer (score 1):

This is Vatsal, from [Branch.io](https://www.branch.io)

Any link scraped by GoogleBot will contain all the backlinks and not just for Google Play. Branch link reacts to user-agents on the browser and then decides which redirection to take. GoogleBot is a scraper and it is designed to scrape all the redirection and not just the operating system based. So when the GoogleBot crawls for Branch link, it will find Google Play as one of the redirection links.

Hope this helps!